# Connect to a MySQL database via Excel online

Tags: mysql, sql, database, excel, vba

We build and deploy excel 'tools' which run queries in VBA from an Access database. However, we want to make this tool available to a client without sending them over an entire database along with the excel file.

**Q**. Can we store a read-only database online, using MySQL or even SQL Express, and allow any machine with our Excel file (and connection setup) to access this? I.e. we want our Excel file to connect to a 'cloud' database

Background: I've used PhpMyAdmin to connect and query databases, but this has always been in a local development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use a connection string in Excel to connect MySQL or SQL Express:

In Excel, go to Data, Connections, Add:

MySQL: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

SQL Express: Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;